# What does "shot" "way" "task" mean for few shot learning? under RL setting as well?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Recently got into few shot learning, and meta-learning

MAML:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.03400.pdf

Reptile:
https://d4mucfpksywv.cloudfront.net/research-covers/reptile/reptile_update.pdf

1) do I understand the purpose of MAML or Reptile by saying the whole point of those meta-learning is to, at the end of the day, find a good initialization of the NN's parameters such that when you use those parameters to train on a specific task, it could learn fast?

2) what specifically do they mean by "X shot, Y way" ? For image classification, there would be total of Y classes, and X examples for each Y class, thus a total of XY pictures in a single task. But under reinforcement learning setting, what does it mean to sample a task? Could a set of tasks be defined as, for example, {space invaders, Go, chess...} ? (in MAML, once you sample a task, you are supposed to run K trajectories). The problem could be, what if each task has different input size? For image classification, you could only select fixed sized pictures, but for RL, the input size could vary.

3) how does Reptile work? It only uses first order optimization, and thus I'd assume it'd be faster to meta-learn. But I'm still not understanding the intuitive reason why Reptile could perform just as well as MAML.